# air html text doesn't display local images

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, textfield, htmltext

I have a swf file created with flash cs4, in that file, I have one TextField which is loading an image that is in the same swf directory through htmlText.

In the other hand I made one air app loading the same swf, but the image is not displaying, anyone knows how to solve it, I searched a lot before asking but I couldn't find something helpful to my case.

Please help me, I really need to know how to do it!!

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: some sample code will help in fixing your problem

Comment: Adrian, look in my flash code I have something like this : 
txt_field.htmlText = '<img src="imgs/img.jpg">';
this in flash player shows the image, but when I load the swf generated with flash into an air project, the image is not shown.

Comment: could you please also try with src="/imgs/img.jpg" ? sometimes flash goes strange. Also do you allow network_access from publishing options ? (I presume /imgs/img.jpg exists inside the /src folder of your AIR project ??

Answer (score 2):

"For AIR content in the application security sandbox, AIR ignores img tags in HTML content in ActionScript TextField objects. This is to prevent possible phishing attacks"

(I know this is old but it was the first solution to come up when I was trying to solve the same issue; so for those that come after me here it is)

From Adobe's user doc on TextFields